# Macro version of RMSE

Tags: measurement-error, weighted-regression

I want to calculate the error of a prediction on an imbalanced dataset, i.e.:

```
true = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
pred = [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

[This paper](https://ieeexplore-ieee-org.proxy.library.ju.se/abstract/document/5364825) suggests using a "Macro version" of standard error functions (MAE, MSE, RMSE).

Where for example the normal MAE:

$$
MAE^{\mu}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)={1\over \vert Te\vert}\sum_{x_{i}\in Te}\vert \hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i})\vert
$$

where $Te$ is a set of samples, $x_i$ are the features for a sample, $\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})$ is a prediction, and $\Phi(x_{i})$ is the true value.

is translated into its macro version:

$$
MAE^{M}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{1\over \vert Te_{j}\vert}\sum_{x_{i}\in Te_{j}}\vert \hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i})\vert
$$

where $n$ is the set of unique classes ($\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ in our case). So they basically perform an average $MAE$ for each class and then average all those errors.

The authors do not specifically write how to do this for $MSE$ but I assume that:

$$
MSE^{\mu}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)={1\over \vert Te\vert }\sum_{x_{i}\in Te}(\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i}))^{2}
$$

would be translated to:

$$
MSE^{M}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{1\over \vert Te_j\vert }\sum_{x_{i}\in Te_j}(\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i}))^{2}
$$

My question is: How would $RMSE^M$ look?

Given the $RMSE^\mu$ formula:

$$
RMSE^{\mu}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)=\sqrt{{1\over \vert Te\vert }\sum_{x_{i}\in Te}(\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i}))^{2}}
$$

Would we expect an average across all classes like:

$$
RMSE^{M}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{{1\over \vert Te_j\vert }\sum_{x_{i}\in Te_j}(\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i}))^{2}} \hspace{2cm}(1)
$$

Or $\sqrt{MSE^M}$ like:

$$
RMSE^{M}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)=\sqrt{{1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{1\over \vert Te_j\vert }\sum_{x_{i}\in Te_j}(\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i}))^{2}} \hspace{2cm}(2)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our professor suggested that the second alternative
$$
RMSE^{M}(\hat{\Phi}, Te)=\sqrt{{1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{1\over \vert Te_j\vert }\sum_{x_{i}\in Te_j}(\hat{\Phi}(x_{i})-\Phi(x_{i}))^{2}} \hspace{2cm}(2)
$$
made the most sense as per the [additive nature or variances](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/additivity_variance/#:%7E:text=Well%2C%20we%20have%20dived%20in,that%20it%20is%20less%20abstract.) you want to average them before taking the square root.